# Package: the importance of naming files when using initialization

Tags: go

I wrote a structure like display in the tree below.

```
.
├── README.md
├── db
│   └── db.go
├── go.mod
├── go.sum
├── handler
│   ├── category.go
│   ├── handler.go
│   └── users.go
├── main.go
├── model
│   ├── category.go
│   ├── model.go
│   └── users.go
└── route
    ├── category.go // init() ❌ error to using package vars
    ├── route.go // init() writing package vars
    └── users.go // init() ✅ no error to using package vars
```

All the files in the packages except the one with the same name *(route/route.go, handler/handler.go,...)* are generated automatically. For these files to extend the package variables, I use golang's `func init(){}` ex:

**route/route.go**

```
package route

import (
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"
    "github.com/labstack/echo/v4/middleware"
)

var (
    // public routes
    e *echo.Echo  = echo.New()
    // restricted routes
    r *echo.Group = e.Group("/restricted")
)

func init() {
    e.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
        AllowOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
        AllowMethods: []string{echo.GET, echo.PUT, echo.POST, echo.DELETE, echo.OPTIONS},
        AllowHeaders: []string{echo.HeaderAuthorization, echo.HeaderContentType},
    }))

    e.Use(middleware.Recover())
    r.Use(middleware.JWT([]byte("secret")))
}
```

**route/category.go**

```
package route

import (
    "github.com/username/project/handler"
)

func init() {
    r.GET("/category", handler.ListCategory)
    r.POST("/category/add", handler.CreateCategory)
    r.GET("/category/:id", handler.ReadCategory)
    r.PUT("/category/edit/:id", handler.UpdateCategory)
    r.DELETE("/category/:id", handler.DeleteCategory)
}
```

**route/user.go**

```
package route

import (
    "github.com/username/project/handler"
)

func init() {
    r.GET("/users", handler.ListUsers)
    r.POST("/users/add", handler.CreateUser)
    r.PUT("/users/edit/:id", handler.UpdateUser)
    r.DELETE("/users/:id", handler.DeleteUser)
    e.POST("/auth", handler.Login)
    e.POST("/lost", handler.Lost)
    e.POST("/password", handler.Password)
}
```

As you already understood, the category.go `init()` starts before the router.go `init()`, which is described [here: Go Package initialization](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_initialization).

After coding a pretty program that auto writes routes like `route/category.go`. I realize that to solve this problem, I will have to rename `router/router.go` to `router/0router.go` *(it works)* so that it is still at the top of the pillar, but it's not a good approach.

Have any suggestions for this tree and the use of golang `ini()` ?

Thank you

Comment: I think It will be more clear If you create single file where you will initialize all `routs`. For example    rename `init()` to `initialize()` in files and call ones from single `int()` per `package`

Comment: Consider not using init() at all, and instead delegate initialization to main(). This makes the code less magic and, more important, easier to test. The init() functionality should be avoided in the majority of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use variable declaration expressions to avoid file name dependencies. The assignments execute before the `init()` functions that reference the variables.

```
var (
    // public routes
    e *echo.Echo = newPublic()
    // restricted routes
    r *echo.Group = newRestricted()
)

func newPublic() *echo.Echo {
    e := echo.New()
    e.Use(middleware.CORSWithConfig(middleware.CORSConfig{
        AllowOrigins: []string{"http://localhost:3000"},
        AllowMethods: []string{echo.GET, echo.PUT, echo.POST, echo.DELETE, echo.OPTIONS},
        AllowHeaders: []string{echo.HeaderAuthorization, echo.HeaderContentType},
    }))
    e.Use(middleware.Recover())
}

func newRestricted() *echo.Group {
    r := e.Group("/restricted")
    r.Use(middleware.JWT([]byte("secret")))
    return r
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will test